# How to transfer file from Windows95 in VMWare to Host OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, file-transfer, vmware-workstation, windows-95

How can I transfer files from Virtual Windows 95 to Host (Windows 10) ?

I tried many things:

- Enable copy and paste in Guest Isolation
- Enable shared folders option but it isn't supported in Windows 95
- Tried USB connection but Windows 95 doesn't see it

Virtual Machine Program: VMWare Workstation 11.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with a Windows guest and Windows host, I would mount the virtual disk on the host.  From the menu, choose File > Map Virtual Disks, click the Map button and select the `.vmdk` file for your Windows 95 VM.

Otherwise I would set up a network share in the Windows 95 VM and access files via that.

Comment: Mapping virtual disks option works perfectly, thanks for simple and efficient answer!

Comment: Any idea how to do it if the Host OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and the Guest is Windows 95?

Comment: @GabrielStaples I'd use an SMB/CIFS network share.  If you want to mount the guest `.vmdk` on the host, you could try `guestmount`, but I have no experience using that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot; I posted a question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153517/how-do-i-share-files-between-a-virtualbox-windows-95-guest-and-ubuntu-18-04-host

Answer (score 0):

In you have network set up, you can try sharing a folder in windows 95, and then accessing from your host.

Right click the folder with the file you want, and choose sharing.
Give the share a name. [for example SHARE-NAME]
Then you should have some dialog to allow access. give "everyone" full control.

After this is set up, go to windows 10.
On your keyboard hit WIN + R , and type `\\ip.address.for.win95\SHARE-NAME`
hit OK

You should get the folder open, and be able to copy the files.

Comment: I opened VMWare Tools -> Shared Folders menu. It says me: "This feature is currently not supported for this guest operating system"

Comment: Can you try from within windows 95?

Comment: Do you have proper network set up on guest [95] ?

Answer (score 0):

you may try create emulated CD in ISO and play it in virtual machine. Adding more files by converting more files into the same ISO image to read by win95.